# Data in SQL Server pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this query

```
select 
    ed.employeeid, e.Namemployee, d.doc_code, d.doc_name, ed.received
from 
    documents_Detail ed 
inner join 
    table_emp e on e.employeeid = ed.employeeid
inner join 
    docum d on d.doc_code = ed.doc_code and ed.received = 'N'
```

This shows data:

```
employeeid  Namemployee doc_code  doc_name         received
-----------------------------------------------------------
23           John       2         Academic_Cert       N                         
23           John       6          Nom_Form           N
```

AND several other different doc_code and data like same.

Required output:

```
employeeid  Nameemployee      Academic_Cert(2)   Nom_Form(6)
-------------------------------------------------------------
23            John              N                  N
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are now without CTE

**Please try this -**, You can make this dynamic.

```
select employeeid,Namemployee,MAX([Academic_Cert(2)]) [Academic_Cert(2)] ,MAX([Nom_Form(6)]) [Nom_Form(6)]  from 
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,CONCAT(doc_name,'(',doc_code,')') dn FROM  
        (
            select 
                ed.employeeid, e.Namemployee, d.doc_code, d.doc_name, ed.received
            from 
                documents_Detail ed 
            inner join 
                table_emp e on e.employeeid = ed.employeeid
            inner join 
                docum d on d.doc_code = ed.doc_code and ed.received = 'N'
        )k
    )u
    pivot
    (
        MAX(received) FOR dn IN ([Academic_Cert(2)],[Nom_Form(6)])
    )p
)cte1
GROUP BY employeeid,Namemployee
```

**OUTPUT**

```
employeeid  Namemployee Academic_Cert(2) Nom_Form(6)
----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
23          John        N                N
```

(1 row affected)

**For making it dynamic please refer this blog post-**
https://msbiskills.com/2017/12/25/sql-puzzle-dynamic-pivot-puzzle/

**Another solution WITHOUT CTE will be**

```
    select employeeid,Namemployee,MAX(CASE WHEN doc_code = 2 THEN [received] END) [Academic_Cert(2)] 
,MAX(CASE WHEN doc_code = 6 THEN [received] END) [Nom_Form(6)]  from 
(
    SELECT *,CONCAT(doc_name,'(',doc_code,')') dn FROM  
    (
        select 
            ed.employeeid, e.Namemployee, d.doc_code, d.doc_name, ed.received
        from 
            documents_Detail ed 
        inner join 
            table_emp e on e.employeeid = ed.employeeid
        inner join 
            docum d on d.doc_code = ed.doc_code and ed.received = 'N'
    )k  
)CTE
GROUP BY employeeid,Namemployee
```

**OUTPUT**

```
employeeid  Namemployee Academic_Cert(2) Nom_Form(6)
----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
23          John        N                N


(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Added one more solution WITHOUT pivot. Thanks

Comment: hi.. i second query you always using CTE ?? and secondly using MAX(CASE WHEN documentcode = 2  .. but i have 15+ codes so this is not possible to wrote individual with max.. another possibility ?

Comment: I have removed the CTEs from both the solutions. For second question- you can make the query dynamic which will easily take care of n number of codes. Please follow the link for dynamic pivoting.  https://msbiskills.com/2017/12/25/sql-puzzle-dynamic-pivot-puzzle/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by executing a dynamic SQL query. For the convenience, the result set can be stored in a temporary table and use that temp table in the dynamic SQL query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select [employeeid], [Namemployee], '
    + stuff((
            select ',max(case [doc_name] when ' + char(39) + [doc_name] + char(39) 
            + ' then ' + char(39) + [received] + char(39) + ' end) as [' + [doc_name] 
            + '(' + cast([doc_code] as varchar(100)) + ')]'
            from #t
            order by [doc_name]
            for xml path('')
        )
        , 1, 1, ''
    );

select @sql += ' from #t group by [employeeid], [Namemployee];';

exec(@sql);
```